# Add char to char array issue, hangman game

Tags: c#, console

the problem is I discovered my approach required the building of a char array -> char[] from multiple char variables.  can someone point me in the right direction?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    string[] wordList = { 
                            "Baseball", "Tackle", "Dubstep", "Ignorance", "Limitation", "Sausage",
                            "Destruction", "Patriot", "Computing", "Assembly", "Coding", "Hackers",
                            "Football", "Downward"
                        };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int guessRemain = 7;
        int wordSel = GenerateRandom();
        Program o = new Program();


        char[] wordChar = o.wordList[wordSel].ToLower().ToCharArray();
        int MAX_BUF = wordChar.Length;


        Console.WriteLine("\nHANGMAN v 1.0\n\n\n\n");
        char[] userInput = PromptUserEntry();
        char[] solution = ScanForMatchingLetter(wordChar, MAX_BUF, userInput);


        Console.Read();
    }
    private static char ScanForMatchingLetter(char[] wordChar, int MAX_BUF, char[] userInput)
    {
        char[] solution = new char[MAX_BUF];
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUF; ++i)
        {
            if (userInput[0] == wordChar[i])
            {
                solution[i] = userInput[0];

            }


        }
        return solution;
    }
    private static char[] PromptUserEntry()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pick a letter:");
        char[] userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
        return userInput;
    }
    private static void DisplayGuessLetterLine(char[] solution)
    {

        Console.Write(solution);

    }
    private static int GenerateRandom()
    {
        Random randNum = new Random();
        int wordSel = randNum.Next(0, 13);
        return wordSel;
    }

}
}
```

I have a return type problem here; the return type is specified as a char but I am returning a char[].

Comment: Don't use an array if you need variable length storage. A `List<char>` would probably work better for you.

Comment: Why do you return a char when you actually need a char[] and the method(`ScanForMatchingLetter`)  even does have a char[]?

Comment: All of your functions are static functions within your class, but your word array is an instance variable. You could apply `static` to `wordList` as well and not create an instance of the Program class like you're doing.  Alternatively, remove `static` from everything, make a non-static method `Run`, and in `Main` simply do `Program o = new Program(); o.Run();`

Comment: Im Working for 3 to 4 hour.. totally lost now /

Comment: okay i applied static to wordlist. now error remains same a about char to char[]

Comment: Change your method `ScanForMatchingLetter` to return a char[]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every instance where you are using char arrays, replace them with with

```
List<char>
```

Lists allow you to add and remove at will, reboxing the underlying array for you so that you don't have to worry about it.

I have updated my answer with your resolution.  Use List instead of char arrays and return only single chars, not arrays, when you only have one user input.  I hope this helps and resolves your question

```
class Program
{
    readonly string[] wordList = { 
                        "Baseball", "Tackle", "Dubstep", "Ignorance", "Limitation", "Sausage",
                        "Destruction", "Patriot", "Computing", "Assembly", "Coding", "Hackers",
                        "Football", "Downward"
                    };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int guessRemain = 7;
        int wordSel = GenerateRandom();
        Program o = new Program();


        List<char> wordChar = o.wordList[wordSel].ToLower().ToList();
        int MAX_BUF = wordChar.Count;


        Console.WriteLine("\nHANGMAN v 1.0\n\n\n\n");
        char userInput = PromptUserEntry();
        List<char> solution = ScanForMatchingLetter(wordChar, MAX_BUF, userInput);


        Console.Read();
    }
    private static List<char> ScanForMatchingLetter(List<char> wordChar, int MAX_BUF, char userInput)
    {
        List<char> solution = new char[MAX_BUF].ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUF; ++i)
        {
            if (userInput == wordChar[i])
            {
                solution[i] = userInput;

            }


        }
        return solution;
    }
    private static char PromptUserEntry()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pick a letter:");
        char userInput = Console.ReadLine()[0];
        return userInput;
    }
    private static void DisplayGuessLetterLine(List<char> solution)
    {

        Console.Write(solution);

    }
    private static int GenerateRandom()
    {
        Random randNum = new Random();
        int wordSel = randNum.Next(0, 13);
        return wordSel;
    }
}
```

Comment: @UmairAslam Please see my update. I think it'll help you quite a bit

Comment: but still its giving some error about conversion. but this time it cannot convert string to character.
what is thay resemble code of tocharArray(); in generic ?
because i think . tolist() is not working

Comment: @UmairAslam Did you use my code exactly as I posted it?  It compiled correctly on my machine and worked perfectly.  Are you able to compile it?

Comment: but Its not compiling in may machine. i copied it from here . but still hav some error

Comment: David it correctly compile now. but not giving accurate answer . is my code is right for hangman game ?

Comment: @UmairAslam From what you have here, the game is not finished.  All it does it just compares the answer to the list of chars by iterating over the members.  You still need to handle that and continue on with the game.  In essence, we've resolved your current issue but you still have a good deal of work to do before you're done.  That said, keep pushing and working on it and if you get stuck, create another question with that answer and we'll be here to help you.